# bsDatepicker .withTimePicker, how to remove AM/PM

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

Im using angular 12 and ngx-bootstrap 7.1.2
When using the datepicker with timepicker, how can i format the timepicker?
In this case i want to remove the AM/PM from it and allow the user to select the time in the 24h format.

This is the code I'm using

```
<div class="text">   
    <input id="dpReview"
           name="dpReview"
           type="text"
           required
           #allocationDatepicker
           class="form-control"
           bsDatepicker
           placeholder="Select an assignment date"
           [(ngModel)]="allocDate"
           [bsConfig]="{withTimepicker: true, dateInputFormat: 'MMMM DD YYYY, HH:mm'}"/>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I also looking how to switch time to 24h format in datepicker. Do you found solution?

Comment: I havent yet. i may come back to this in a few weeks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue too, apparently the datepicker doesn't support configuring the timepicker integrated within, even though the timepicker itself actually does support it (an even has an `@Input` for it).

I use Angular 15 with `ngx-bootstrap@10.3.0`.

I was able to resolve my issue with a sort of hack-ish workaround. Let me be clear, this is not a recommended solution as it depends on some internal functionality of both the datepicker and timepicker. If the internals change (e.g. private property or method names) the workaround will stop working or (while improbable) can introduce glitches in the datepicker or timepicker.
I only used it myself to temporarily work around the issue for now, but eventually I will replace the datepicker with a custom implementation.

The datepicker has an event emitter `onShown`, which can be used to perform some initialization. In my case it's accessing the timepicker component inside it and override a private method responsible for rendering the time.

```html
<input id="dpReview"
       name="dpReview"
       type="text"
       bsDatepicker
       #allocationDatepicker="bsDatepicker"
       (onShown)="initDatepicker(allocationDatepicker)"
       .../>
```

```ts
// TODO fix me properly!
// hack timepicker to show 24h instead of 12h format
initDatepicker(dp: BsDatepickerDirective): void {
  // defer execution until reference to datepicker container is initialized
  setTimeout(() => {
    const timepicker = (dp as any)._datepickerRef.instance.startTimepicker!;
  
    // override rendering method
    const originalMethod = timepicker._renderTime as (value?: string | Date) => void;
    const newMethod = (value?: string | Date) => {
      // set the "showMeridian" property to false and call original method
      timepicker.showMeridian = false;
      originalMethod.call(timepicker, value);
      // reset back to true to avoid an infinite loop
      timepicker.showMeridian = true;
    };
    timepicker._renderTime = newMethod;

    // re-render time in case it's initialized with a 00 or 12+ hour
    timepicker._store.select((state: TimepickerState) => state.value)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((value: Date | undefined) => {
        newMethod(value);
        timepicker._cd.markForCheck();
      });
  });
}
```

As you see, the `showMeridian` property is the one for responsible for rendering the 12h format, see [timepicker code on github](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/v10.3.0/src/timepicker/timepicker.component.ts#L410).
This hack only briefly sets it to `false` and then back to `true` again after the rendering. Note that I tried to just set `timepicker.showMeridian = false` upon initialization instead, but that resulted in strange behavior and the rendering method being called endlessly, effectivelly stopping the page from working.

While this example works, I discourage its usage long-term and instead recommend either implementing your own datepicker (maybe just by combining the bootstrap datepicker and timepicker yourself) or using a different library altogether.